# Version control for Rails in a Windows environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, version-control

I'm coding a Rails project in a Windows environment and using Eclipse (with the Aptana plug-in) as my development environment.

I'm far enough along in my project now that I don't want to lose any of my work, and would like to start version controlling it.

What would you suggest I use?  I've Googled and seen some responses for Git and TortoiseSVN, but I like the responses I usually get from the StackOverflow crowd.  Anything that integrates well with Eclipse?  Or are they all command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's plugin named [Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/) that provides SVN support for Eclipse.

There're several git plugins but I am not sure they are stable enough.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial!

With Mercurial, you get distributed version control, [Eclipse plugin support](http://www.eclipseplugincentral.com/Web_Links-index-req-viewlink-cid-676.html), and [TortoiseHg](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/Home).  Subversion was great back when everyone was just getting over CVS, but these days, the benefits of DVCS are too numerous to ignore.  I personally prefer git to Mercurial, but git just isn't ready on the Windows environment.  Hopefully Git# will fix that, but you have to wait for that.

Hopefully you're only developing in Windows and not deploying there?  Rails and a Windows environment for production is a painful combination.